# Bringing documents parts of Word 2007 to a single xml document

Tags: xml, word-2007

I created a zip file of a word 2007 document with a single line refering to msdn tutorials. This resulted in the folders _rels, CustomXml, docProps, and word folders which have some xml files in them. Now I need to put all those xml files into one single document(which will be very lengthy) and still be able to open it with Word 2007. I simply put the contents of the xml files into a single document and saved it with .xml extention, but I was not able to open it with Word 2007. It tells some parts are invalid. Can someone please help.

Comment: It would help to analyze your problem if you provided a link to the MSDN tutorial you mentioned or even better this single line of code.

Comment: Let's forget about the single line. :) It doesn't matter even if it is a blank document without any content. The link is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264572(v=office.12).aspx. Thanks.

Comment: I followed the tutorial and ended up with a valid (though empty) Open Xml Document which could be opened in Wordpad (don't have Word 2007 here to test). The only issue I see is that the tutorial keeps talking about creating folders named "root" which is nonsense since all illustrations show a root folder named "simpledocument". I used "Send to -> Compressed (zipped) folder" to create the zip archive from this "simpledocument" folder and changed the extension from .zip to .docx and it opened without any problems.

Comment: I have no problem with creating a docx from the zip. I need to add the content of the xml files in the _rels, CustomXml, docProps, and word folders in to one xml document (which will named with .xml extention) and open that xml document with Word 2007. Thanks.